# Simple split string not working in zapier

Tags: python, split, zapier

I'm using `zapier` to put different apps together. I need to split a string `custom_id` that has 6 parts that are separated by an underscore. For example, `sk000_i093_14.50_5_MNE_2017-07-25`

Here's my code:

```
split_str = input_data['custom_id'].split("_")

output = [{'sk':split_str[0], 'buy_invoice':split_str[1], 'sales_amt':split_str[2], 'UPI':split_str[3], 'buyer':split_str[4], 'date_buy':split_str[5]}]
```

I also tried it this way:

```
sk, buy_invoice, sales_amt, upi, buyer, date_buy = input_data['custom_id'].split("_")

output = [{'sk':sk, 'buy_invoice':buy_invoice, 'sales_amt':sales_amt, 'upi':upi, 'buyer':buyer, 'date_buy':date_buy}]
```

I've searched and searched and haven't found anything specific to `zapier` on why my simple split string isn't working with zapier. When I test the code `zapier` doesn't give a useful error message, just:

> "Bargle. We hit an error creating a run python. Error:  Your code had
>   an error!"

I've tried running it multiple ways, but whenever I try to retrieve the data from the split I get the very unhelpful error message.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE:
When you go to test the code, Zapier shows test data for input_data. Even though this data is showing up correctly, during the actual test run input_data is empty! So there was nothing wrong with the split. Phew!

Thanks!

Comment: you need to check the length of the `split_str` list before trying to access the indexes with `split_str[2] or [3]...`, the same for the unpacking in your 2nd solution

Comment: I suggest that you look at `input_data['custom_id']` to ensure that it really points to a string with the format you currently suppose.
Likely errors are: the string does not exist, the string does not have the format you expect, the number of split items does not match the number of you expect, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. That got me one step closer: Zapier shows that my test data is correct, but in the actually test run input_data is empty! I emailed Zapier. Hopefully they can resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The split was correct. The problem was input_data wasn't being populated, even though Zapier showed the correct data was going to populate it, input_data was empty anyway. I added some more key:value pairs to input_data because I needed them, refreshed the webpage, refreshed the fields, and re-tested the code, and input_data finally got populated and the code ran perfectly.

Thanks to PRMoureu and E. Ducateme for giving me the idea to check my input_data (Duh!).